# Javascript/Jquery change class of Select after selecting option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

So I have a Select Box whose color is Grey but after selecting an option the color of the box should turn black. I am Using the following code to accomplish this event

```js
$('.change_color').on("change",function() {
  $(this).removeClass('grey_color');
  $(this).addClass('black_color');
});
```

```css
.grey_color{
    color: #999;
}
.black_color{
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="change_color grey_color">
 <option>12th Standard</option>
 <option>High School</option>
 <option>First Year</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I Can't seem to figure out my error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be styling the option tag, rather than the select?

Comment: Its working fine. At start it's grey after selection it turns black. What issue you are facing?

Comment: do you mean background-color?

Comment: Just to make sure; you have included jQuery somewhere before your own script, right?

Comment: Just FYI the select isn't grey at all on my screen (Chrome on OSX). This is why it's almost pointless styling a `select` element. If you need to, look in to using a third party library to convert the select control to HTML, such as select2. Also what if someone wants to choose `12th Standard` and doesn't change the box? It would be grey as if it was incomplete, yet is on the right option.

Comment: Seems to be working fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrjGEO

Comment: Now I m running my own code snippet its running fine here on stack overflow but its not working on my project. problem is something else i suppose.

Comment: Which browser? Version?

Comment: It worked i just had to add document.ready. thank u guys for commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working as per your requirement.

Here is the link to code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrjGEO

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Select Box</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
            integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        .grey_color {
            color: #999;
        }

        .black_color {
            color: #000;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.change_color').on("change", function () {
                $(this).removeClass('grey_color');
                $(this).addClass('black_color');
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select class="change_color grey_color">
            <option>12th Standard</option>
            <option>High School</option>
            <option>First Year</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let opt = document.querySelector(".change_color");

opt.addEventListener("change", function() {
  this.classList.remove("grey_color");
  this.classList.add("black_color");
  console.log(1);
});
```

```css
.grey_color {
  background: #999;
}
.black_color {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select class="change_color grey_color">
    <option>12th Standard</option>
    <option>High School</option>
    <option>First Year</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I think is because you can't change the color of the text?i really don't know why but i do know is it work for me

Comment: Now I m running my own code snippet its running fine on stack overflow but its not working on my project. problem is something else i suppose.

Comment: If you can please make a Gits about your code,i think that will help?

Comment: i just had to add document.ready .. now its working fine. thank u for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be working (although you can lose the `script` tags around the JavaScript/jQuery code within the snippet). The color of your select list changes from grey to black when something is selected.

```js
$('.change_color').on("change",function() {
  $(this).removeClass('grey_color');
  $(this).addClass('black_color');
});
```

```css
.grey_color{
    color: #999;
}
.black_color{
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select class="change_color grey_color">
 <option>12th Standard</option>
 <option>High School</option>
 <option>First Year</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Are you expecting the background color to change instead of the text color? You can alter the CSS to have it change the `background-color` property if that's what you were intending? See below:

```js
$('.change_color').on("change",function() {
  $(this).removeClass('grey_color');
  $(this).addClass('black_color');
});
```

```css
.grey_color{
    color: #999;
    background-color: none;
}
.black_color{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select class="change_color grey_color">
 <option>12th Standard</option>
 <option>High School</option>
 <option>First Year</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but you have the css classes setting the color property, which changes the text color. If you want to change the background colors, then you have to use the background-color property.

```
.grey_color {
  background-color: #999;
}
.black_color {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add  $(document).ready around my script and now its working perfectly fine.

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.change_color').on("change", function () {
                $(this).removeClass('grey_color');
                $(this).addClass('black_color');
            });
        });

    </script>
```